# Validating non-required associative array with required fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I want to validate that if my request contains a field of associative array type, that array needs to contain specific fields (but only if it's present)

Ie, array, if present, needs to contain foo:

```
{ data: {}}
```

and

```
{ data: { array: { foo: 1 } }
```

is fine, but

```
{ data: { array: {} }
```

and

```
{ data: { array: { bar: 1 } }
```

is not.

I've written this validator:

```
['data.array' => 'sometimes', 'data.array.foo' => 'required']
```

But it doesn't accept the first scenario.

```
>>> \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(
   ['data' => []], 
   ['data.array' => 'sometimes', 'data.array.foo' => 'required']
)->errors()->all();
=> [
     "The data.array.foo field is required.",
   ]
```

I'd like to avoid using `'data.array.foo' => 'required_with:data.array'` (it also doesn't work for scenario when array is empty)

```
>>> \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make(
   ['data' => ['array' => []]], 
   ['data.array' => 'sometimes', 'data.array.foo' => 'required_with:data.array']
)->errors()->all();
=> []
```

Are there any non-custom validators that will help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `Rule::requiredIf` after Laravel 5.6 and up, try this:

```
$validator =  Validator::make( $request->input(), [
    // ...
    'data.array.foo'=> Rule::requiredIf( function () use ($request){
        return (bool) $request->input('data.array');
    })
]);
```

Comment: This works, however the validation is awkward and boils down to `make data.array.foo required if data.array has any value`. Ideally, would want to validate `data.array` per two rules `data.array can be present` and `data.array.foo is required` but can admit that this might be the only way to accomplish what I'm after.